# Plot Wind Barb in R

Tags: r, plot, weather

This is more a question to see if anyone has seen anything like this in their travels. I am working with a lot of weather data and I would like to plot wind based on [wind barbs](https://www.google.ca/search?q=wind+barb+R&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=1115&tbm=isch&imgil=E1NutljD2cP95M%253A%253BgWMVCSWYpXEVgM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fmatplotlib.org%25252Fexamples%25252Fpylab_examples%25252Fbarb_demo.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=E1NutljD2cP95M%253A%252CgWMVCSWYpXEVgM%252C_&usg=__VPc39S9RYmsCH1Lh-yDm9vM_ZSQ%3D&ved=0CC8QyjdqFQoTCPqWhYaJicgCFYJQiAodg-ADdg&ei=iXYAVrquNYKhoQSDwY-wBw#imgrc=E1NutljD2cP95M%3A&usg=__VPc39S9RYmsCH1Lh-yDm9vM_ZSQ%3D).

I have looked into the package `RadioSonde` however its `plotwind()` function is not doing the job I had anticipated. It does have a good example of the type of data `data(ExampleSonde)`

Arguably I can use `TeachingDemos` in conjunction with `my.symbols()` to create these wind barbs. I was just curious if anyone has found (or created) a way to plot wind barbs. Otherwise `my.symbols()` it is.

Thanks,

Badger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to create the wind barbs using `grid` graphics.

First step is to calculate how many, and what type of barb is needed. As described [here](http://weather.rap.ucar.edu/info/about_windbarb.html), I created three types, that represent 50, 10, and 5 knots - I round down the speed to the nearest five.

The function below `wind_barb` generates a new grob for each wind speed it is given. Using an idea from [Integrating Grid Graphics Output with Base Graphics Output - Murrell (pg4)](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjACahUKEwjGnpTM_JLIAhUDVxoKHZmfBNQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FgridBase%2Fvignettes%2FgridBase.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHaZu3qEMNQp6PmfT1sS3qHBl9R4Q&bvm=bv.103627116,d.bGg) you can plot the grobs easily and represent the wind direction by rotating the viewport.

An example

Create some data

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=-2:2, y=-2:2, 
                  direction=sample(0:360, 5), 
                  speed=c(10, 15, 50, 75, 100))
#    x  y direction speed
# 1 -2 -2        95    10
# 2 -1 -1       133    15
# 3  0  0       205    50
# 4  1  1       325    75
# 5  2  2        72   100
```

Plot

```
library(gridBase)
library(grid)

with(dat, plot(x, y, ylim=c(-3, 3), xlim=c(-3, 3), pch=16))

vps <- baseViewports()
pushViewport(vps$inner, vps$figure, vps$plot)
# Plot
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
    pushViewport(viewport(
                    x=unit(dat$x[i], "native"),
                    y=unit(dat$y[i], "native"), 
                    angle=dat$direction[i]))
        wind_barb(dat$speed[i])
    popViewport()
  }

popViewport(3)
```

Which produces

[image]

`wind_barb` function to create barbs (please simplify me!). You can change the height and width of the barb by adjusting `mlength` and `wblength` arguments respectively.

```
wind_barb <- function(x, mlength=0.1, wblength=0.025) {

  # Calculate which / how many barbs
    # any triangles (50)
    fif <- floor(x /50)
    # and then look for longer lines for remaining speed (10)
    tn <- floor( (x - fif* 50)/10)
    # and then look for shorter lines for remaining speed (5)
    fv <- floor( (x - fif* 50 - tn* 10)/5)

    # Spacing & barb length
    yadj <- 0.5+mlength
    dist <- (yadj-0.5) / 10    
    xadj <- 0.5+wblength
    xfadj <- 0.5+wblength/2        

  # Create grobs
    main_grob <- linesGrob(0.5, c(0.5, yadj ))

    # 50 windspeed
    if(fif != 0) {
      fify <- c(yadj, yadj-dist*seq_len(2* fif) )
      fifx <- c(0.5, xadj)[rep(1:2, length=length(fify))]
      fif_grob <- pathGrob(fifx, fify, gp=gpar(fill="black"))
    } else {
      fif_grob <- NULL
      fify <- yadj+dist
    }

    # Ten windspeed
    if(tn != 0) {
    tny <- lapply(seq_len(tn) , function(x) min(fify) - dist*c(x, x-1))  
    tn_grob <- do.call(gList, 
                      mapply(function(x,y) 
                             linesGrob(x=x, y=y, gp=gpar(fill="black")),
                                      x=list(c(0.5, xadj)), y=tny, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
    } else {
      tn_grob <- NULL
      tny <- fify
    }

    # Five windspeed
    if(fv != 0) {
    fvy <- lapply(seq_len(fv) , function(x) min(unlist(tny)) -dist* c(x, x-0.5))
    fv_grob <- do.call(gList, 
                        mapply(function(x,y) 
                              linesGrob(x=x, y=y, gp=gpar(fill="black")),
                                      x=list(c(0.5, xfadj)), y=fvy, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
    } else {
      fv_grob <- NULL
    }    

    # Draw    
    #grid.newpage()
    grid.draw(gList(main_grob, fif_grob, tn_grob, fv_grob))
}
```

### -------------------------------------

**comment from sezen below**

> The plotted wind direction is wrong. To have right meteorological wind direction, use `angle = 360 - dat$direction[i]`. See http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m430/Wind/WindDirection.html

Comment: This is phenomena, thank you so much! I've seen this question in many places I'll be sure to link those folks back to your answer here. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Honey, appreciate the comment. It does need a bit of tidying up; i've not really used grid much so there will be a way to more efficiently control the grob sizes, and perhaps it is worth doing the actual plotting in grid as well (thats for another day).

Comment: This is a huge launching point for us, if we do any cleaning I'll be sure to post it here as an update to where things have gone. As it stands I have already applied it to some real data and it looks great. Just gotta swap it over to metric ;)

Comment: My 2 cents... The plotted wind direction is wrong. To have right meteorological wind direction, use `angle = 360 - dat$direction[i]`. One careless can use this code and overlook the results. See [here](http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m430/Wind/WindDirection.html)

Comment: Cheers,@Sezen, not my subject so ive added your comment so people are aware of issue. [ i really should rewrite this!]

Comment: @user20650 Thank you very much for the code. This is the best wind barb plotting that I've seen so far. I've used your code in a **panel function** of `lattice::xyplot`.  A complete windbarb function definetely will fill the lack of windbarb in R.

Comment: @user20650--i have a question regarding the plot. I tried to plot the barbs using your script but when the wind speed is about 5 knts, it is hard to distinguish from the 10knts. I changed the color instead. How do you add an extra line in the 5knts barb?Here is the output of my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sdz38lmoepidp9/test.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @Lyndz ; its probably not placed correctly on the spine by the function, the five knot barb should start a little down the spine - I need to spend a bit of time to rewrite this this. Maybe at the w/end. (but what do you mean to add an extra line on the 5knts barb ; to give what knots?)

Comment: @user20650-Thank you for the response. I was wondering if there is a way to create a new line just a little lower in your original script if the wind speed is 5knts (and below) then if it is 10 knts and above, the function will use your original script. I tried editting your script by adding these lines inside the #Five windspeed but it messes the orientation of the line (not straight) : **if(fv != 0) { yadj <- 0.5+mlength  dist <- (yadj-0.5) / 7**. The new output is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c81lk1qu5yz9y58/test_2.pdf?dl=0. I'm also a beginner in r. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lyndz ; yes, i think that is the right idea - the images of 5 knot wind barb's tend tp start a bit lower on the spine, although I think the function need s to be rethought rather than just tweaked a bit.